Getting 405 Method Not Allowed on heroku container:push
I've been trying many different Dockerfile configurations: single stage, multi-stage, using ENTRYPOINT, using CMD, running as root, running as a user, etc. But I run this:
heroku login
heroku container:login
heroku container:push l2d -a like-to-discover

I've also tried:
heroku login
heroku container login
docker build -t l2d .
docker tag l2d registry.heroku.com/like-to-discover/l2d
docker push registry.heroku.com/like-to-discover/l2d

And I get this error:
The push refers to repository [registry.heroku.com/like-to-discover/l2d]
7bf68bbab835: Layer already exists 
9fa5be66deab: Pushed 
cc346f687dc2: Layer already exists 
559a76444520: Layer already exists 
3d03b9efaa15: Layer already exists 
fe58f5e24c8d: Layer already exists 
68c164eb7734: Layer already exists 
989c04d82f10: Layer already exists 
8f558c57d2b0: Layer already exists 
failed commit on ref "manifest-sha256:55b80333170d88d82ab936d33656e7eff89ab37812bcb3bd746f724961b78a0c": unexpected status from PUT request to https://registry.heroku.com/v2/like-to-discover/l2d/manifests/latest: 405 Method Not Allowed
 ▸    Error: docker push exited with Error: 1

I'm not sure what to do. I've tried a great many things, but I feel like I'm just missing something simple.
Here is my Dockerfile for reference:
FROM python:3.12 as builder

RUN pip install poetry

ENV POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=1 \
    POETRY_CACHE_DIR=/tmp/poetry_cache

WORKDIR /app

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock README.md ./

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=$POETRY_CACHE_DIR poetry install --without dev --no-root

FROM python:3.12-slim as runtime

RUN useradd -m myuser

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/app/.venv \
    PATH="/app/.venv/bin:/app/l2d:$PATH"

COPY --from=builder --chown=myuser:myuser ${VIRTUAL_ENV} ${VIRTUAL_ENV}

COPY --chown=myuser:myuser l2d ./l2d

USER myuser

CMD ["python", "-m", "l2d", "run"]


Any luck with this? I've hit the same problem and can't find a solution…

It may be related to provenance being enabled in BuildKit 0.11: https://help.heroku.com/74S3XXMP/workaround-for-docker-push-error-405-method-not-allowed-using-buildkit-0-11
I was able to push again after using docker build --provenance false
